# Find script that changed the value attribute of a <input /> tag

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

```html
<form id="search" action="/search" method="get" autocomplete="off">
  <div>
    <input type="button" name="test_button" value="test" />
  </div>
</form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("test_button").value = "changed_test"
</script>
```

Just as the HTML code above shows, I have defined a button with name `test_button` and value `test` and changing its value with the code in the script tag.

Now I am debugging a large webpage which is using a mechanism like this using Firebug and Firefox in Linux.

I want to know how I can find the script that changes the `value` attribute of the `<input ... />`, but the web page is too large, various `<script>` and anonymous functions which are auto-executed made it nearly impossible to find the specific `script` manually.

Since I am in Linux, I cannot use any Microsoft tools to search the whole web page. I only have Firebug and Chrome. Can Firebug realize that? Does anyone have a good idea of how to find the specific `<script>` that changed the `value`?

Comment: This is rather unclear, and you seem to post the script that alters the button value; other than that, use your browser's 'Find' feature to loop through instances of the string 'test_button' to see where it is used.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I think the code is just an example that represents the core problem, and the actual document being debugged is much bigger (and probably has the equivalent of "test_button" all over the place).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Add some code like this to the document, right after the form with the button:

```
<script>
var node = document.getElementById("test_button");
Object.defineProperty(node, 'value', {
    set: function() { throw new Error('button value modified'); }
});
</script>
```

This will throw an error when anything tries to modify the button's `value`.

[image: error log]

Expand the error and click the last line number shown. This will take you straight to the line that set the value of the button.

[image: offending script line]

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XSJZN/

Tested in Chrome 17.

Comment: thx a lot. what you have written is really very detailed. and its indeed a good idea. but i need to debug a website that isnt written by me, for i need write a web crawler on that website. i remembered that chrome developer tools have such a function. e.g.  for the line: `<input type = "button" id = “btn” value = "test_button">`, i can right click the line, and choose, "break when the attribute modification", then refresh the webpage, and chrome will stop at tge line where the attribute is modified, dosent firebug have a similar function?