# Find the jquery function who did modify a html element

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging a website that has a href tag on it.
The url are removed in the dom, but in the source it's still is in there..

Is there away that i can click on the tag(start point of the search) and see in the google chrome toolbar which function modify it?
(even listeners > change is not the one that show who did change it in the state how it's now)

I search in the libary's but that's about 32 files :s i couldn't find it. Google didn't help ether to find a solution.. ...

Comment: Could you be more precise please? What do you mean by "in the source it's still in there"? Also more details about the code would be helpful to understand what you are trying to solve.

Comment: You can try to adapt the script in the answer of this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687593/how-to-find-script-that-changed-the-value-attribute-of-a-input-tag

Comment: I think you'd be better of just searching the source-code for `.attr('href'`, `.prop('href'` or just `'href'` (and also try double-quotes). Another option would be adding breakpoints or step-by-step javascript execution in chrome debugger..

Comment: If by source you mean the page source code (CTRL/CMD + U), JS has no effect on this. Also, be aware that the dom showed in inspector doesnt always reflect reality.

Comment: in the dom "<a>Products</a>"  in the source it's   "<a href="/products/">Products</a>" 
So the href is removed... i can't find the function that remove the href..

Is it possible to see the changes/stacks of that href who change that tag

@FLX looks like a idea but didn't get it work yet. Give me a error on the script line not who change it..

Answer (score 4):

You can set breakpoints on HTML using *chrome developer tools*.  There is a option that lets you `break on subtree modification`, which will cause the browser to break on the lines of JS that cause modifications to the html.

Open developers tools and navigate to to the elements tab, find the html element you are trying to watch, right-click on its parent element and select `break on -> subtree modification` to make chrome stop on a breakpoint in ur js whenever the child elements are added/removed/modified.

EDIT: [image: Here is the option]

Comment: Great answer! I see you can also select `break on..` > `attributes modifications` on the element itself!

Comment: It is definitely possible to put a breakpoint on `<html>` tag. [Look here](http://i.imgur.com/Wf5tLc5.png)

Comment: I did put the break on about 10x on diffrents places on the html.. but it doesn't stop. it just load the page

Comment: Even after setting the breakpoint in Html and refreshing it didn't stop in js?

Comment: @James yes it just load the page.. i put in on header what you have showen

Comment: You can try setting the breakpoint on a element that you added in html and modify in ur own code, just to see if it's working.  Or try to get a html breakpoint working on a different site. If you know where in the js code the dom manipulation occurs, u can set a breakpoint on the line just before it and step over a couple lines to see if it triggers the breakpoint in the html.

Comment: @James  i tray it on a different page 'jQuery("header a").removeAttr("href");'  and put a breakpoint on there but it doesn't break it..

Comment: That's very odd. If i put a breakpoint the html tag of this page, stackoverflow.com, and refresh the browser it stops. Does it work for u as well?  If not, it's something else