# Find the script changing an HTML tag's content

Tags: javascript, html

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687593/find-script-that-changed-the-value-attribute-of-a-input-tag), except I'm not looking for the script that changed the "value attribute" of the tag, but the actual content of it.

For example, in a page there is:

```
<div id="mouseYDiv">Mouse Y is 312.</div>
```

Whenever I move the mouse, the content of this div changes. How do I find the exact code that does this?

Comment: Search for something like `document.getElementById('mouseYDiv').textContent` or `document.getElementById('mouseYDiv').innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for changes to its `textContent`, `innerHTML`, or `innerText`:

```
const elm = document.querySelector('#mouseYDiv');
['innerHTML', 'textContent', 'innerText'].forEach((propName) => {
  Object.defineProperty(node, propName, {
    set() { throw new Error('value modified'); },
    // if the script also needs to retrieve the element's value:
    get() {
      const { get } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, propName);
      return get.call(this);
    }
  });
});
```

Then check the stack trace.

Comment: Perfect, exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Chrome DevTools, you can set a breakpoint on any element like below.

[image: Chrome DevTools]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can search three things

1. Check for any `mouseover` event
2. Check for any `mouseeneter` event
3. Check if there is any document.getElementById('mouseYDiv').addEventListener

other than this you can also look for if there is any `document.querySlectorAll` or `document.getElementsByTagName`